# Json array element access

Tags: php

Actually I have an array. that array convert to `JSON` encodes format. but I can't access all the names from `JSON` array. now I want to access all the names. Is it possible?

```
[{"name":"JANETS","count":2},{"name":"ROYR","count":2}]
```

Comment: please post the code that isn't working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not magento related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(["name" => "JANETS", "count" => 2], ["name" => "ROYR", "count" => 2]);

var_dump(json_encode($arr));
//Output:
/*[
    {
      "name": "JANETS",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "ROYR",
      "count": 2
    }
  ]*/


foreach ($arr as $val) {
    echo $val['name'].'<br>';
    //Output
    /*
    JANETS
    ROYR
    */
}
```